# React Native image and other components does not respect bounds (Such as padding)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have recently started using React-Native, and one of the main issues I have been struggling with is the layout design.

I have a "Card" like component that holds some information about movies. Components like Image and Text that are big goes out of the bounds of the card and does not respect the padding and margins provided.

Here is the JSX code:

```
            <View style={[styles.container, styles.card]}>
            <View style={{alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row', padding: 10}}>
                <Image style={{height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 25}}
                       source={require('../../img/sarah-avatar.png.jpeg')}/>

                <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', marginTop: 5, marginLeft: 15}}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{ this.state.movie.name }</Text>
                    <Text style={{color: 'gray'}}>{ moment(this.state.movie.releaseDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY') }</Text>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <!-- THIS IMAGE DOES NOT RESPECT THE CARD BOUNDS -->
                <Image style={{height: 220, resizeMode: 'center'}}
                       source={require('../../img/advance-card-bttf.png')}/>

                <View style={{flexWrap: 'wrap', marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 20}}>

                    <Text style={{color: 'gray', fontSize: 14}}>
                        { this.state.movie.summary }
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1}}>
                <Button onPress={this.onLikeClick.bind(this)}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <Icon name="thumbs-up" size={18} color="#007aff" />
                        <Text style={{color: '#007aff', marginLeft: 5}}>{ this.state.movie.likes } Likes</Text>
                    </View>
                </Button>

                <View style={{width: 20}} />

                <Button onPress={this.onCommentClick.bind(this)}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <Icon name="comment" size={18} color="#007aff" />
                        <Text style={{color: '#007aff', marginLeft: 5}}>{ this.state.movie.comments.length } Comments</Text>
                    </View>
                </Button>
            </View>

            <Comments comments={this.state.movie.comments }
                      showComments={ this.state.showComments }
                      handler={this.handler} />
        </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderRadius: 2,
        shadowColor: "#000000",
        shadowOpacity: 0.3,
        shadowRadius: 1,
        shadowOffset: {
            height: 1,
            width: 0.3,
        },
        padding: 10,
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        margin: 5
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    button: {
        marginRight: 10
    }
});
```

And the comments component JSX code:

```
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
            {
                this.props.comments.map((comment, index) => {
                    return (
                        <View key={index} style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 20}}>
                            <Image style={{height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 25}}
                                   source={require('../../img/avatar-ts-woody.png')}/>

                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', marginLeft: 15, marginTop: 3}}>
                                <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>{ comment.name }</Text>
                                <!-- THE COMMENT CONTENT GOES OUTSIDE OF THE CARD -->
                                <Text style={{color: 'gray'}}>{ comment.content }</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    )
                })
            }

            <TextInput placeholder="Leave a comment"
                       value={this.state.commentContent}
                       onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({commentContent : text})}
                       onSubmitEditing={this.onCommentEntered.bind(this)}
                       style={{height: 40, marginTop: 18}} />
        </View>
```

Here you can see that the cover image seems like it's out of the card:
[image: As you can the the cover image does not respect the card bounds]

In here each comment might start correctly inside the card, but will go outside of the bounds when text is too long:
[image: In this picture, each comment text goes out of the card bounds]

Comment: Try `resizeMode: 'contain'`

Comment: It doesn't work as well. It just seems so weird that components inside a view goes out of the view without any reason \: